# Added Next/Previous buttons to Rails view. Why is Next skipping some instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I've added Next and Previous buttons to cycle through views of a resource on a Rails 3.2 app. Next and Previous should just cycle through the ID.

The Previous button works as expected: it's a link to (the current ID minus 1).

However, the Next button links to arbitrary ID numbers. For any ID less than 17, the Next button links to ID number 17. Clicking that shows a Next button linking to 31, then 45, then 58, 59, 65, 82, 108, 115, 120, 127, 128, 129, 131, ... From there, gaps are less frequent but still do appear.

The resource is called Lecture, so here's the relevant part of app/models/lecture.rb:

```
def previous
  Lecture.where(["id < ?", id]).last
end

def next
  Lecture.where(["id > ?", id]).first
end
```

And here's the view, app/views/lectures/show.html.erb:

```
<li class="previous">
  <%= link_to "Previous", @lecture.previous if @lecture.previous.present? %>
</li>
<li class="next">
  <%= link_to "Next", @lecture.next if @lecture.next.present? %>
</li>
```

**The production data for the Resource lecture actually has continuous IDs all the way from 1 to 173.**

I suspect this is an issue related to batch-editing my production data, but I can think of no way to be sure. I'm on Heroku/postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Heroku Postgres, the standard SQL gotcha applies:

**Unless you explicitly specify an order, the order of records returned by an SQL query is undefined.**

Your `previous` and `next` code assumes the query results will be ordered by ID, but that's not what you're getting back; Postgres is returning whatever records are most convenient, wherever it's most convenient.

Chaining a simple [`order`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508815/added-next-previous-buttons-to-rails-view-why-is-next-skipping-some-instances) onto your query will get you the records in the order you expect:

```
Lecture.where(["id < ?", id]).order('id').last
```

(You can, of course, replace `id` with any other column if it makes more sense to traverse the records by some other criteria.)

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head. Explicitly ordering by id fixed the problem perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! It's easy to get bitten by this one; modern PG is more aggressive in optimizing requests than some other SQL implementations.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that they follow the order of your models' ID's, try making the changes to your methods below:

```
def previous
  Lecture.where(["id < ?", id]).order(:id).last
end

def next
  Lecture.where(["id > ?", id]).order(:id).first
end
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You won by 2 minutes with the right solution. Thank you for that! I learned something from colinm, so I marked his answer for the sake of less-technical posterity :)